# Convert a number to another number using specified operations. Need some help regarding this

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

This was a problem I came across recently-

> Suppose I've 3 integers k,m,n. I have to reach **m** from **k** in minimum number of operations, and the operations possible are-
>
> You can multiply **k** by **n**.
>
> You can decrease **k** by 2.
>
> You can decrease **k** by 1.
>
> Also, these 3 operations can be performed in any order.

There are a number of ways to try this out- be it *recursion* or the *dynamic* approach. But I found an interesting solution to this which implemented neither of them, and I'm having a hard time deciphering it. Here's the code for reference-

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        while (k < m) {
            if (m % n == 0) {
                m = m / n;
                count++;
            } else {
                x = (n - (m % n));
                m += (x) / 2 * 2 + (x) % 2;
                count += x / 2 + x % 2;
            }
        }
        if (k > m) {
            count += (k - m) / 2 + (k - m) % 2;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Well, I'm really sorry for not being able to include comments, as I'm not able to get a hang of this code. Can someone please go through the code once, and explain how does this code actually work? It would be of great help! (By the way, the code runs fine!)

Comment: the best way to approach this problem is to download IntelliJ and then use the greatest debugger ever created to step through the code while it is running, to understand what it does

Comment: I'm still on it btw.

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on the Intellij debugger at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html. Youtube is also a great source for learning the Intellij debugger. Good luck!

Comment: Well, I use Intellij, but never heard of this feature! Will it really help me to get me started with understanding this code?

Comment: the debugger allows to step through your code while running it. You will see all the values at the same time and you are even able to execute code at the current position, by right clicking into the debugger and selecting 'Evaluate Expression'. It helps me a lot. You can also set the debugger to automatically show you code that causes exceptions. Or you can make it show you when a variable changed. I've found so many errors by using this tool. And it also helps you understand what is going on

Comment: I've posted a comented version of your code down below

Comment: I've found out that the line: 'm += x / 2 * 2 + x % 2;' is exactly the same as 'm += x;'

Comment: this code will hang if you specify n=1

Comment: Obviously if n is 1, you can't reach a number greater than **k** given the operations.

Comment: yeah you should change it to while (k < m && n != 1) or smthing like this

Comment: this code fails on input `2,5,6` output should be `5` it gives `3`

Comment: No? I've explicily mentioned that the operations can be performed in any order, which makes this problem challenging. You can subtract 1 from 2, then multiply by 6, then subtract 1 again and voila! You reach 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IntoVoid for putting up the comments. Actually, I needed a bit of help in understanding the code :) I'm somewhat familiar with the Java structure, I just needed a bit of insight into the algo used in the code to solve the problem.

Comment: I think I'm on to something

Comment: Give me a second

Comment: nope does not work

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks.

Comment: The algorithm is trying to reach `k` from `m` till `m > k`. Then it reaches `m` from `k`.

Comment: so what it does is: It rounds m up to an even multiple of n and then divides m by n. Then roundes m up to an even multiple of n and then divides it again. And so on, until m is smaller or equal to k

Comment: i figured that out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832561/13187363 (in the edit part of my previous answer)

Comment: ok I understand it now

Comment: I will post a full explaination down below

Comment: done. I hope you understand it

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66833446/13187363

Comment: Your question seems to be a generalised version of the problem [Two Buttons](https://codeforces.com/contest/520/problem/B), where you can only subtract `1` and multiply by `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what the algorithm basically does is the following:

1. round the current m up to an even multiple of n, but only if m isn't an even multiple of n already and then divide m by n. The first part can be done using the following line (It will result in 0 if m is already an even multiple of n):

> x = n - (m - 1) % n - 1;

by adding x to m we will make m an even multiple of n or keep m as is if it already is one.

2. BUT we can also use x to calculate our number of operations performed.

> You can multiply k by n. You can decrease k by 2. You can decrease k by 1

meaning that if we apply these rules to m then they should be something like (correct me if I'm wrong):

> You can divide m by n. You can increase m by 2. You can increase m by 1

3. So every time we round m to the next even multiple of n we basically say that we increase m's value by 2 'x / 2 times', but since this only works if x is even, we could also say that we increase m by an extra 1 if x is not even.

> So for this step we need to increase our count value by 'x / 2 + x % 2'

4. Now that we've done this we need to divide m by n (As my inverted rules for m instead of k say, you can do that now). After dividing m by n, we need to add 1 to the counter, since we performed one operation.

---

### And here is the full condensed code:

```
int count = 0, x;
while (k < m) {
    x = n - (m - 1) % n - 1;
    m = (m + x) / n;
    count += x / 2 + x % 2 + 1;
}
if (k > m) {
    count += (k - m) / 2 + (k - m) % 2;
}
```

---

### Conclusion:

This algorithm performs all operations on m and not on k as the rules suggest.
Therefore you need to "reverse" the rules (like I did above)
And then you analyse the code with your "new" set of rules and figure out that it basically already follows your "new" set of rules. Coincidence, I don't think so!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: See my other answer for full explaination (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66833446/13187363)

EDIT:
You could shorten the algorithm itself to:

```
while (k < m) {
    m += n - (m - 1) % n - 1;
    m /= n;
}
```

but I didn't figure the count value out yet

**Previous:**
Here is a commented version (also reformatting helps a lot):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int k = sc.nextInt();
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    sc.close();

    int count = 0, x;
    while (k < m) { // Loop while k is smaller then m (meaning our end goal for m is to be smaller or equal to k) (since k will not change inside of the while loop we know that m must change)
        if (m % n == 0) { // Check if m divided by n has NO remainder, if so do the division and increase count by one
            m = m / n;
            count++;
        } else { // If not then...
            // ...subtract the remainder from n and store it in x. X now contains the number which you would need to add to m to make 'm % n == 0' (the if statement) result in true
            x = (n - (m % n));

            // In here we do 'x / 2 * 2' first which will result in even value (rounding x to its lower even value. eg. x = 5 would become 4. Since we are using integers) which we then add to m.
            // Then we also add the missing '1' to m to make the if statement in the next loop result in true
            // I tested this algorithm btw. it does not change the value of x:
            /*
                for (int x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {
                    boolean same = x == (x / 2 * 2 + x % 2);
                    System.out.println(x + " -> " + same);
                }
                Result: same is always true
            */
            m += x / 2 * 2 + x % 2; // This line can be simplified to 'm += x;'
            
            // Then we add half of the x and a 0 or a 1 to count
            count += x / 2 + x % 2;
        }
    }
    if (k > m) { // This will run always if k is not eual to m
        
        // This line is almost equal to this one: 'count += x / 2 + x % 2;'
        // except, that every x was replaced by '(k - m)'
        
        count += (k - m) / 2 + (k - m) % 2;
    }
    
    // Then we print out count
    System.out.println(count);
```